# Scope of Models(?) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to access my site's database. I generated and set up a model and controller called Machine, and noticed that in places like the Machine view I could iterate through all the machines in my database simply using @machines.each. However, this doesn't appear to be universal, as when I created a new Ruby file directly in my project's outermost directory, both @machines.each and the attempted assignment @machines = Machine.all threw errors (a NoMethodError and NameError respectively). Here's an example of code I could try to run:

```rb
@machines = Machine.all

@machines.each do |machine|
  puts machine.created_at
end
```

Perhaps I need some kind of import statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a script in plain Ruby -- then yes, you'll have to import everything manually, establish a connection to the DB, etc.

The code would roughly look like this:

```rb
require 'active_support'
require 'active_record'

your_db_config = {
  # your DB config goes here
}

ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths += File.join(__dir__, "app/models")
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(your_db_config)

machines = Machine.all
```

Consider creating a [task](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#custom-rake-tasks) if you want Rails to take care of all that and don't want to be doing all that stuff manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you start a rails server (or a rails console) it preloads your Rails application so that your models, constants, etc. are automatically in scope. If you want to access your application's resources from a separate script you still need to load the app. The simplest way to do that is with the `rails runner` command, which loads your app and then executes a script. So if your script above is in `lib/show_machines` you'd run:

```
$ bin/rails runner lib/show_machines
```

If you like self-executing scripts you can also use runner as a 'shebang' line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env <your_project_path>/rails/runner    
@machines = Machine.all

@machines.each do |machine|
  puts machine.created_at
end
```